# How to group pages in fastreport.net?

Tags: c#, fastreport

I generate report by following query using 3 tables and I need to start every date on a new page but all the rows is bottom of other
How can I break rows of any date to a new page

```
select PM_Report.*,PM_Scores.*,PM_Table.* from PM_Report left outer 
       join PM_Scores on PM_Report.date=PM_Scores.date and
       PM_Report.period=PM_Scores.period left outer join PM_Table 
       on PM_Table.row=PM_Scores.row and PM_Table.period=PM_Scores.period 
       where PM_Table.period='daily' and PM_Report.date between 
       '2015/05/01' and '2015/05/05' order by PM_Report.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a `GroupHeader` or `GroupFooter` to the `data` band
2. Set the `GroupCondition` of the Group to be `date` or whatever is your date column name is.
3. Set `StartNewPage` property of `GroupHeader` or `GroupFooter` to be `true`